# Dynamically change images in a LyX File

Tags: graphics, lyx, pdf, report

I am using LyX and have created a document that includes numerous images.  I'm wondering if it's possible to reference the path and file name to the images in LyX so that when I compile and create my PDF document, the new images with the same file name as the old file name referenced in the document will be displayed?

For example, when I originally create my document I will have a reference to `myimage1.pdf`.  When I compile my document I see `myimage1.pdf` just fine as I would expect.  However, my LyX document contains some code that executes external program code that generates new graphics when LyX the document is compiled and the PDF generated.  After generating a new PDF, I'd like my LyX document to pull in the newly created myimage1.pdf.  Currently, LyX seems to be rending the document with the old image.  When I generate the document a second time, it pulls in the correct images (presumably because the new `myimpage1.pdf` is available initially at run-time).  Is there any way to get this to work without have the image available in advance of generating my PDF?

Comment: TeX will grab whatever is available in the form of `myimage1.pdf` at the time of compilation. Are you saying that you change `myimage1.pdf` during compilation?

Comment: Yes, myimage1.pdf changes at compile time.

Comment: @Werner This would need some more info and a small example. When I am thinking about embedded R code (i.e. sweave or knitr), this should be handled as expected, i.e code executed and graph generated and inserted. Other code might have different approaches. Without further info, I would suggest to look at the copiers in LyX, or the command line compilation of the LyX document, so that you could e.g. run it twice?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is possible, so forcing a second compilation is likely the only option.